# Content of image not being displayed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, browser, blob

I have a Blob of an image which I need to display in browser. The code provided below opens the image but shows some Mandarin scripts on the window.

Code:

```
var url="http://....link..../downloadFile?fdsFileId="+fileId;
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: url,
        responseType: 'arraybuffer'
    }).success(function (data, status, headers) {
        headers = headers();
        var contentType = headers['content-type'];
        var blob = new Blob([data], { type: contentType });
        var fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        console.log("url:"+fileURL);
        console.log("content type:"+contentType);
        window.open(fileURL);
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(fileURL);
```

The image displayed is as below:
The fileURL is provided in the browser.
[image: Click here to see the picture of the result.]

Comment: Have you tried setting content-type : 'image/png'?

Comment: see the url prefix `blob`. You can read  [here](http://superuser.com/questions/948738/what-is-the-blobhttp-prefix-and-where-can-i-learn-more-about-this) about URL schemes.

Comment: @NagaveerGowda: that thing is set by the contentType var. It detects the kind of file and works accordingly. I am using same code for downloading as well and there it works fine but not here.

Comment: @IhorKorotenko: what is wrong in that BLOB URL?

Comment: what happens if you use `responseType: 'blob'`?

Comment: @georgeawg: need to check.

Comment: Setting content-type : 'image/png' worked. Thanks @NagaveerGowda

Comment: However the file I want to view can be of any type. How to implement this? Using type: 'application/octet-stream' opens download file dialog box.

Comment: Just now made content-type:'' (blank) and it works.

Answer (score 0):

set `content-type : 'image/png'` for png images and respectively for other files as well.
For all files support, set `content-type : ''`
Hope it helps.

Edit1:
setting `content-type : ''` did not work in chrome. Hence I had to extract the file extensions from the corresponding filename and then set the content-type using if-else.